# What are some good foods for a puppy?

Tags: dogs, health, diet

I adopted a six month old Labrador/Golden Retriever mixed puppy. What are some good foods for my little puppy?

[image]
<sup>Photo by OP</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your price range:

1) Grocery store food - Iams Puppy

2) Pet Store Food - Acana or Blue Buffalo Puppy

3) Veterinary Food - Royal Canin or Hills Puppy

Once your dog is neutered keep an eye on his weight, you may have to alter the amount he gets or switch to an adult food.

There will always be a lot of controversy on diets just keep in mind that every dog is different and what will work for someone's dog  may not work for yours. The only food I would truly stay away from are RAW diets, it is a health risk to the general public (children, elderly and pregnant women) and to your pets if not properly balanced.

If you would like to make your own dog food I recommend [Hilary's blend](http://completeandbalanced.com/), the recipes are balanced to prevent any deficiencies and approved by veterinary nutritionists.

All life stages dog foods are also no good, there is no such thing, each stage of life needs a different % of nutrients.

Don't give in to the marketing that all foods with corn are bad, in cheaper foods they are bad because the digestibility is very low where as in veterinary food digestibility is high (L.I.P greater than 90%) and it makes for a good source of energy. You'll also see a lot of "gluten free" or "wheat free", all marketing gimmicks, the only time you'd need a wheat free diet is if your dog is allergic to wheat.

A nice indicator on how well it works is quality of skin and coat - your pets fur should not be brittle or greasy and his skin should not be dry and flaky.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Purina all naturals it is an affordable choice of food that does Not have grain as the first ingredient. Instead it has chicken or beef byproducts as the first ingredient. Science diet is usually provided by the vet practice and although it is expensive it is OK to dilute the primary good choice with A less expensive food for vitamins and nutrients. Honestly I feel it is best to get the best food that you can afford, with the most natural ingredients. Having your pet eat well is one way to prevent disease sickness and aging of your pet. The healthier the diet the better- like preventive care. Keep an eye on your pets weight. The heavier the animal the faster is ages., Also I cook high protein foods for my pets. You may be interested in how easily you can make food for your pets. And treats too! https://www.petcarerx.com/article/how-to-make-homemade-dog-food-for-labradors/231